# Customizing UIToolBar the foursquare way

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitoolbar

I'd like to customize my `UIToolBar`, so **the centered button looks something similar to the check-in foursquare button**.

I've seen a commercial source code called [ALToolBar](http://www.mobilebricks.com/ios/altoolbar), wich is similar to the effect I want  on my `UIToolBar`. So in resume, changing the height of a button, and the background of a specific button, if that is the right way to go.

I'm pretty new to iOS, but comfortable enough to dig ideas the community can bring on.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to just write your own Tabbar/Toolbar instead of using the built-in classes. Subclass `UIView` and add UIButtons for each item, which you can then customize as you wish.

The downside to this approach is, you loose the "More" functionality, that allows you to drag-and-drop items into the Tabbar, but if you just have 5 or fewer items, that's fine.

Comment: +1. But, I'd add; you don't "lose" anything you're willing to do yourself. Nothing is stopping someone from replicating the drag-and-drop items feature.

Comment: Great solution, I'll go on this way. Thanks for helping ! (I was taking the problem by the wrong side)

Comment: This is finally what I did, it was very easy and clean. Thanks again.